# Help me reformat my PHP Validation Code

Tags: php

I have designed a file upload form in PHP where it takes 3 pictures and stores it as a varchar datatype in database and move it to the destination directory.

before uploading or inserting the values to the database i want to make sure that

a) it is of file type image/jpeg

b) the three images should have a different fixed dimensions values (which i am fetching the dimension values from getimagesize(); and validating it)

c) and to check if the duplicate of file name exist in the directory (which i am checking through file_exists())

if any one of the conditions returns false then the script should die()

I have defined the code for it but the problem with my code is, if the last condition returns false then the upper conditions will execute the code and do some operations like move_uploaded_file which i dont want to happen, please have a look at the code

Please check the last 4 if conditions as i want that to reformat.

```
$w_title = 685;
    $h_title = 50;
    $w_brief = 685;
    $h_brief = 177;
    $w_detail = 685;

        if(empty($_POST['ns_title']) || empty($_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["name"]) || empty($_FILES["ns_pic_brief"]["name"]) || empty($_FILES["ns_pic_detail"]["name"])) {
           echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . "alert(\"Please Fill All the Required Fields\");" . "</script>"; 
           echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;post-news.php\"/>";
           die();
        }
        else {
            $ns_title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ns_title'])));
            if($_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" && $_FILES["ns_pic_brief"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" && $_FILES["ns_pic_detail"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") {

                $ns_pic_title_loc= $_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["tmp_name"];
                $ns_pic_title_name = $_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["name"];
                list($width_title, $height_title) = getimagesize($ns_pic_title_loc);

                $ns_pic_brief_loc = $_FILES["ns_pic_brief"]["tmp_name"];
                $ns_pic_brief_name = $_FILES["ns_pic_brief"]["name"];
                list($width_brief, $height_brief) = getimagesize($ns_pic_brief_loc);

                $ns_pic_detail_loc = $_FILES["ns_pic_detail"]["tmp_name"];
                $ns_pic_detail_name = $_FILES["ns_pic_detail"]["name"];
                list($width_detail, $height_detail) = getimagesize($ns_pic_detail_loc);

                if(file_exists($ns_target.$ns_pic_title_name)) {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . "alert(\"File Already Exists, Please Choose a Different Name for the File\");" . "</script>";
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;post-news.php\"/>";
                    die();
                }

                if(!$width_title == $w_title && !$height_title == $h_title) {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . "alert(\"Incorrect File Dimension for Title News, please make sure it is (685 X 50)\");" . "</script>";
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;post-news.php\"/>";
                    die();
                }
                else {
                    move_uploaded_file($ns_pic_title_loc, $ns_target.$ns_pic_title_name);
                }

                if(!$width_brief == $w_brief && !$height_brief == $h_brief) {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . "alert(\"Incorrect File Dimension for Brief News, please make sure it is (685 X 177)\");" . "</script>";
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;post-news.php\"/>";
                    die();
                }
                else {
                    move_uploaded_file($ns_pic_brief_loc, $ns_target.$ns_pic_brief_name);
                }
                if(!$width_detail == $w_detail) {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . "alert(\"Incorrect File Dimension for Detail News, please make sure it is (685 in width)\");" . "</script>";
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;post-news.php\"/>";
                    die();
                }
                else {
                    move_uploaded_file($ns_pic_brief_loc, $ns_target.$ns_pic_brief_name);
                }
```

how do i reformat the code so that

a) it should check all the three condition

b) and if any one of it returns false then it should stop the execution at once

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend moving your logic to a function to reduce duplication.

**Note**: I have no way to test any of this, so won't try, but it should get you started.

```
function fail($error)
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $error . '");</script>';
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;post-news.php"/>';
}

function valid_image($image, $width, $height = 0)
{
  if ($image['type'] != 'image/jpeg')
  {
    fail('File must be of type image/jpeg');
    return false;
  }

  if(file_exists($ns_target . $image['name']))
  {
    fail('File Already Exists, Please Choose a Different Name for the File');
    return false;
  }

  list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);
  if ($image_width != $width || ($image_height && $image_height != $height))
  {
    fail('Incorrect File Dimension for ' . $image['name'] .
      ', please make sure it is (' . $width .
      ($height ? ' X ' . $height  : ' in width'). ')');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

if(empty($_POST['ns_title']) ||
  empty($_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["name"]) ||
  empty($_FILES["ns_pic_brief"]["name"]) ||
  empty($_FILES["ns_pic_detail"]["name"]))
{
  fail('Please Fill All the Required Fields');
  die();
}

if (valid_image($_FILES['ns_pic_title'], 685, 50) &&
  valid_image($_FILES['ns_pic_brief'], 685, 177) &&
  valid_image($_FILES['ns_pic_detail'], 685))
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ns_pic_title']['tmp_name'],
    $ns_target . $_FILES['ns_pic_title']['name']);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ns_pic_brief']['tmp_name'],
    $ns_target . $_FILES['ns_pic_brief']['name']);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ns_pic_detail']['tmp_name'],
    $ns_target . $_FILES['ns_pic_detail']['name']);
}
```

Comment: Brandon, I would suggest one change: In `fail()` use `die` instead of `echo`. That way you don't need `return` statements in `valid_image()`, also in the current implementation you continue to check all conditions even when an earlier one has failed. If `die` is used in `fail`, you'd quit at first exception.

Comment: +1 This is Brilliant i am still a bit newbie, while i will try and change my code to functions, that looks pretty decent and neat too, i appreciate the pain you took to go through my post and replying it.

Comment: I am unable to use the fail() in PHP? isnt it supposed to be the PHP function,? i would appreciate if i get any reference from php site, i am unable to find it

Comment: Just FYI i changed my code to function with reference of your code, and you cannot imagine the amount of code i reduced. this is so awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a few tips:

**No need for `if ... else`**
You can simplify the code by reducing nesting.

This is **bad**

```
if(cond) {
  do this;
  die();
} else {
  do other things
}
```

Change above to:

```
if(cond) {
  do this;
  die();
}
do other things
```

If in the above code, all you want to do is to output some text you can further simplify it as

```
if(cond) die('text to output');
do other things
```

**Check for exception, not conformance**
Instead of

```
if($_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" && ...) {
  do stuff
  ...
```

Use

```
if($_FILES["ns_pic_title"]["type"] !== "image/jpeg" || ...) exit;
do stuff
...
```

**Use comments**
even if the code is for your personal consumption, use as much comments as you can, virtually no amount of comment is too much.

Comment: Thank you  for that kind and helpful that, i am on the verge of solving my problem and i am using the exact same pattern suggested by you.. i appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Ibrahim Glad it helped. Take a look at the `fail` function in Brandon's answer, it is much better than warping your error message in `<script type ...` every time.

Comment: I am unable to use the fail() in PHP? isnt it supposed to be the PHP function,? i would appreciate if i get any reference from php site, i am unable to find it

Comment: In PHP you can write your own functions and they are called `user-defined`. `fail` is a user defined function writen by Brandon in his answer above (it is lines 1 to 5 of his answer).